# Why my background images on iPhone messed up and they're appear normal on browser?

Tags: html, css, iphone, image, media-queries

I am having an issue resizing my background images for the iPhone. When I'm in developer mode they appear normal but on iPhone they're blurry and messed up (see pics for difference). [image: Desktop]  [image: iPhone]

The first pic is what it's suppose to look like for the iPhone. I tried everything I could think of. Please visit http://nlm-marketing.herokuapp.com/ and if you have an iPhone, view it from there so you'll see exactly what I'm talking about. Please help. Thanks!

CSS

```
@media only screen /*iPhone*/
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  {




    .img-bg {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url('/images/341778467.jpg') no-repeat center center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: auto !important;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;


    }

}
```

Comment: do you want bluer image use css3 filters in your media query

Comment: @Yaseen What do you mean?

Comment: review this url http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_filter_blur

Comment: Thanks but the image still needs resizing. How can I position the image  and make it clear exactly like the first pic above?

Comment: give the max height and with in px the size of devices.

Comment: What do you mean with in the px the size?

Comment: px mean pixels  use this in your class .img-bg  min-with:320px  min-height:568px

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110361/discussion-between-michael-stokes-and-yaseen).

Answer (score 0):

use this code i hope it's work for you

**CSS**

```
@media only screen /*iPhone*/
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  {



.img-bg {


height: 650px;
    padding: 300px;
    background:  url('img2.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.img-bg  p {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 50px !important;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif !important;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
    left: 17%;
}

.img-bg2 {
    padding: 330px;
    background: url('img1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.img-bg2  p {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
    margin-top: -100px;

}

.content {
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #212121;
}

.content p {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.content2 {
    height: 900px;
}


#content {
    padding: 200px;
    background-color: #282829;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content"> 

<div class="content">
    <div class="img-bg">
        <p id='title'>  Established in 2004,  </p>
    </div>

    <p><strong><span id='span-one'style='color:#fff; font-size: 45px; font-family: Work Sans; text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;'> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex</p>
</div>

<div class="content2">
    <div class="img-bg2">
        <p><strong><span id='span-two'style='font-family: Work Sans; color:#fff ; font-size: 2em; font-style: italic'></span></strong> Throughout the years NLM Marketing has established extensive relationships with the leading distributors that have helped propel many products in becoming household name brands. Our staff consist of professionals with extensive experience in the Meat, Dairy, Frozen, Deli and Seafood categories. NLM and its staff have become the link between Manufactures, Packers, Distributors and owners/managers of Key Retailers.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```